# Opencv - mask image results in black image

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I want to mask a colored image, but the result I get is a completely black image, my code is:

```
Mat maskOriginal(Mat src, Mat original, Mat mask) {

    original.copyTo(src, mask);
    return src;
}
```

My mask is a one channel(CV_8U) black/white image.
My mask:
[image]

Comment: Please upload the mask as well ?

Comment: @Zdar - edited.

Comment: Can you show where you use the maskOriginal function ?

Comment: @Sunreef - My program just call this function and then I print the returned img, I'm not with the source now, but I'll post ASAP.

Comment: and this is related to java how??

Answer (score 1):

When applying a mask you should be careful that both the src and the original image have the same number of channel otherwise copyTo will seamlessly realocate a  new black image. From the opencv doc :

> The method copies the matrix data to another matrix. Before copying the data, the method invokes
>
> `m.create(this->size(), this->type());`
>
> so that the destination matrix is reallocated if needed.

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=clone#mat-copyTo

If the two types don't match you can use for example the `cvtColor` method to change the color, example to convert CV_8UC4 to CV_8UC3 you would do something like :

`cvtColor(original,original,COLOR_BGRA2BGR);`

Answer (score 0):

Note, how maskOriginal is used and pay attention to mask elements type.
For given image the code below will keep a circle in the middle of input image, while filling the rest with black.

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("image.png");
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1);

cv::circle(mask, cv::Point(img.cols/2, img.rows/2), 
           std::min(img.rows, img.cols)/2, cv::Scalar(255), -1);

cv::Mat result;
result = maskOriginal(result, img, mask);

cv::namedWindow("result");
cv::imshow("result", result);

cv::waitKey();
```